# Find x for a portion of arc-length of 3rd order poly when full length known.

Tags: geometry, polynomials, arc-length

Heads up.. I am in no way good at maths so be gentle with me.

I am trying to find x for a portion of arc-length of 3rd order poly when full length, function, and limits are known. The full length has be determined by $l= \int \sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2} dx$. (If anyone got a better way please let me know!). I basically want to know how I would make x the subject in the previous equation so that I can calculate x at say 75% of the full arc length of curve. I would need to be able to adapt the answer to computer code.

Thanks

Comment: How can it be that you know the full length ?

Comment: I have used the arc length formula above to determine length at upper limit. Is that what you mean Yves?

Comment: For a cubic polynomial, this is close to untractable. How did you manage ?

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I am supposed to say estimated full length?

Comment: Sorry Claude, yes I was using the formula as you have written, Typo on my behalf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ the integral is

$$s_{01}=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\sqrt{1+(3ax^2+2bx+c)^2}dx.$$

This is a nasty one, which requires the use of elliptic integrals, and the resulting function must be inverted. All of this must be done numerically and will be quite complicated.

An easier approach is by solving the differential equation

$$\frac{dx}{ds}=\frac1{\sqrt{1+P'^2(x)}}$$ using a numerical solver such as Runge-Kutta. You will step until $s$ reaches the $75\%$ of the full length (presumably obtained by a preliminary numerical integration over the whole $x$ range).

---

For a poor man's solution, flatten the curve (i.e. decompose it into a polyline made of short segments), and compute the cumulated segment lengths. This will give you an estimate of the full length. Then backtrack to find the segment where $75\%$ of the full length was crossed and perform linear interpolation to improve the estimate.

---

A more sophisticated but very accurate method is by decomposing the curve into circular arcs rather than line segments, by estimating osculatory circles from point triples. The fitting will be accurate to second order. Then the computation of the cumulated length along the polyarc is straigthforward.

Comment: I think that your last suggestion is really the most practical. Otherwise, it could be quite complex (as you wrote). Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Yves. I was hoping to cheat and avoid numerical analysis. I will go back and see what I can do with what you have given me. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: my third method is the best compromise between complexit and accuracy, but requires more skills. Anyway, the RK approach isn't that difficult as it uses a standard numerical method.

Comment: Sure, it is not difficult...but requires a computer instead of just a spreadsheet !

Comment: @Tick_hoges: my second method is simple and doesn't require a numerical package. (Though it is the Euler method in disguise.)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: alternatively, use a grapher and a piece of thread ;-)

Comment: Don't worry, I have already had a piece of string up against my screen! Thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When full arc length $s_{max}$ known and you wish to find $x$ as a fraction of it, (although a bit tough now), numerical curvature basis is perhaps more satisfying as it supplies $(x,y)$ as a function of arc length.

In the handwritten note there is an uncorrected error in first equation of (3) independent variable should be $s$ not $x$.

[image]